# How can I get the type of the implementation class stored in the variable declared in the interface type by Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

How can I get the type of the implementation class stored in the variable declared in the interface type by Java reflection?

If you check the type of list variable declared as `List` type using `getDeclaredField()`, it will be obtained as List.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    
    private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field f = Test.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        String type = f.getType().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(type); //output "List"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get it as an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `getClass()` method instead of `reflection`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(list.getClass().getSimpleName()); //ArrayList
    }
}
```

Using reflection its possible. You need to read the type of the value assigned to the variable:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field f = Test.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        String type = f.get(new Object()).getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(type); //output "ArrayList"
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to provide an object when reading a `static` field and providing an object of a class not being assignable to the field’s declaring class is even more misguiding. So, use `f.get(null)` instead of `f.get(new Object())`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. That same variable could hold something entirely different, later; perhaps some code someplace will execute `Test.list = new LinkedList<>()`. What you want to know is unanswerable.

Perhaps you'd want to dig into the assigning expression but that's no joy either. Behold:

```java
private static List<String> list = Math.random() > 0.5 ?
  new LinkedList<>() :
  new ArrayList();
```

You see how this just isn't a question that has a meaningful answer.